# Rendering partials anywhere on your rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a conversation partial with route being resources:conversations, but when i try to render this partial in my navigation bar (to list all their active conversations), i get an undefined method error.

```
undefined method `author' for nil:NilClass
```

Right now i'm doing `<%= render 'conversations/conversation' %>`

Is there a special way to render your partials ANYWHERE on your website?

EDIT: Providing codes

conversations/_conversation.html.erb

```
<div>
  From <strong><%= conversation.author.email %></strong> to
  <strong><%= conversation.receiver.email %> (<%#= conversation.receiver.online? ? 'online' : 'offline' %>)</strong>
  <br>
  <%= link_to 'View conversation', conversation_path(conversation) %>
  <hr>
</div>
```

layouts/_navigation.html.erb

```
  <%= render 'conversations/conversation' %>
```

routes

```
  #Chat
  resources :conversations
  resources :personal_messages
  resources :users
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

EDIT2:

conversations_controller.rb

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_conversation
  before_action :check_participating!, except: [:index]

  def index
    @conversations = Conversation.participating(current_user).order('updated_at DESC')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def show
    @personal_message = PersonalMessage.new
    @conversations = Conversation.participating(current_user)
  end

  private

  def set_conversation
    @conversation = Conversation.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def check_participating!
    redirect_to root_path unless @conversation && @conversation.participates?(current_user)
  end
end
```

applicationcontroller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :authenticate_user!

end
```

Comment: could you provide some code?

Comment: what method is it saying is undefined?

Comment: render partial: 'conversation/conversation', locals: {conversation: conversation}?

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to do this is:

```
render(partial: 'conversations/conversation', object: @conversation)
```

If you don't provide a reference object there's no data binding to the local `conversation` variable and you get the `nil` reference error.

Comment: This presumes there's an instance variable `@conversation` that's defined. I don't know if that's the case. This is just an example. If you don't have a Conversation record loaded none of this code will work.

Comment: It's defined in the conversations controller, but not the applications controller. Is that possibly why? 

Seems odd to not be able to render a partial anywhere you want on your page, without doing a lot of extra work.

Comment: You're putting it in your navigation so I'm presuming this will load on every page. Normally that means you need to promote the code that loads it to the ApplicationController. You can render a partial anywhere you want *provided* you've loaded the data necessary to render it.

Comment: I've never done this 'promote the code that loads it to the application controller". Is there documentation or an example of this? (I also updated the post to show the conversations controller).

Comment: It's pretty simple: Just move the `before_action` and associated code from your ConversationsController to ApplicationController. Keep in mind anything like `params[:id]` will have to be resolved some other way, you'll need to figure out *what* conversation you're displaying in your navigation somehow.